# Are these two methods together a form of recursion?

Tags: java, c#, .net, loops, recursion

I have two methods, the first method calls the second method from within a forloop, but the second method calls the first method back with a sub item id. Is this a form of recursion? Though the same method doesn't call itself, is there any risk of stack overflow or any others issues that may be associated with normal recursive methods?

```
void AddItems(int id)
{
   var items = GetItems(id);

   foreach (var item in items)
   {
      AddItem(item);
   }
}

void AddItem(Item item)
{
   DoSomething(item);
   AddItems(item.subItemId);
}
```

EDIT:
Is there a way to make this iterative? I'm using C#.

Comment: Yes, that's recursion.

Comment: @Stewart Is there a way to make this non-recursive?

Comment: This is typically called [mutual recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_recursion).

Answer (score 5):

As a rule of thumb, if it calls itself, directly or indirectly, on the same or on different data it **is** recursion.

Unless it is tail-recursive (which this is not), recursion is prone to stack overflows. In particular, a `subItemId` that is the same as its parent ID would lead to a cycle, causing SO.

Comment: I note that the C# compiler does not detect and optimize tail-recursive algorithms, though the jitter in some cases can do so.

Answer (score 3):

> Is this a form of recursion?

Yes; this is *mutual recursion*.

> Is there any risk of stack overflow or any others issues that may be associated with normal recursive methods?

Yes.

> Is there a way to make this iterative?

Yes. All recursive algorithms have an iterative form, so this one does. I note that there is no requirement that the iterative form be easy to find or easy to understand.  In this case however the iterative algorithm is very well known; this is a *depth first tree traversal*. Do a web search on that and you'll quickly learn how to use an explicit stack or explicit queue to manage tree traversals iteratively.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't *direct* recursion because recursion is defined as *a method calls itself*. But in your case, there is *indirect* recursion. So, yes, you run the risk of `StackOverFlowError`

Answer (score 0):

yes ,It is fairly simple:

```
void AddItems(int id) {
    tempID = id;
    bool loop = true;
    while(loop) {
        var items = GetItems(id);
        for each(var item in Items) {
            DoSomething(item);
            id = item.subitemID;
            continue;
        }
        loop = false;
    }
}
```

Haven't tested it..But should do the trick...
You might also want to take a look at GOTO statement 
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/13940fs2.aspx

Comment: @EricLippert:  Okay.I will test it

Answer (score -3):

Recursion occurs when a function calls itself. In both void item()s, the function calls itself. However, each recursive function needs a base case or it will recurse infinitely which will be the case here. Do your homework, there are tons of websites explaining recursion.

Comment: Strictly speaking, there could be a base case if a sub item list is empty.

Comment: Just citing sources: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson16.html, unable to find my University book digitally, but this is pretty much the standard explanation used in literature. Yes, there would be a base case if a sub item list is empty.